# How do I use curl wttr.in to get just the number value of the current temperature without the added +/- and F information?

Tags: batch-file

We have a small radio station which is fully automated and it dawned on my if I could pull the current temperature via command line I might be able to push an audio file matching the current temperature to our playout system, but I don't really have the ability to know how to parse the value out completely given wttr.in returns the number with + or - in front of it and the degree and F designation after.

Is it possible to get just the number that I can possibly code as part of my pushout file name so that, for instance, if its 62ºF here, our system pulls "62.FLAC?" I can do the insert easily via task scheduler, just trying to wrap my head around how to possibly automate this with wttr.in.

Thanks!

Tried the usual/generic "curl wttr.in/Amsterdam?format=%t" format, FWIW.

Comment: At a guess, given the scant data displayed, `for /f "delims=." %%e in ('curl wttr.in/Amsterdam?format=%%t') do echo %%e` should do the job, assuming `curl wttr.in/Amsterdam?format=%t` produces `62.FLAC` with or without the `?`. Note the doubling of the `%`

Comment: @Magoo don't forget you need to escape the `=`

Comment: I took a slightly different route because I didn't want to have to extract the number between the +/- and degrees symbol. `for /F "tokens=2 delims= " %%G IN ('curl wttr.in/ORD?format^=p1 2^>nul^|findstr /i /RC:"temperature_fahrenheit.*current"') do set "temp=%%G"`

Comment: Oh - I did forget that. Should be `format^=%%t`, not `format=%%t`

Comment: Thank you! This works and does what I'm after:

for /F "tokens=2 delims= " %%G IN ('curl wttr.in/ORD?format^=p1 2^>nul^|findstr /i /RC:"temperature_fahrenheit.*current"') do set "temp=%%G"
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Winamp\winamp.exe" /ADD \\QUEUE "%temp%.flac"

Comment: Sadly, the `curl` response is `+11°C` not `62.FLAC?` as posted, so my suggestion won't work.

Comment: Oh wait, I realized that it's not doing my local temperature. How in this do I add my local city? It's not Amsterdam! 

for /F "tokens=2 delims= " %%G IN ('curl wttr.in/ORD?format^=p1 2^>nul^|findstr /i /RC:"temperature_fahrenheit.*current"') do set "temp=%%G"

Edit...obviously ORD changed to my local town did it. (Duh.) Thank you all so much!

Comment: @typecrazy789 I just used the closest major airport to where I live to verify the temperature for my testing.

Comment: I realize I'm veering off the original topic here but if we wanted to have option 2 that functioned the same way but pulled a condition audio file would I just change temperature_fahrenheit to weather_condition_textual_name or are there other ways to do it using Promethus? In other words, to get "sunny.flac?"

Comment: Have you tried `%C` instead of `%t`? It returns text like "Partly cloudy" or "Light rain". `for /f "delims=" %%G in ('"curl -s wttr.in/?format=%%C"') do "P:\ath to\winamp.exe" /ADD "%%G.flac"` should work fine. (wttr.in tries to guess your location by your IP or your internet provider's IP. `curl wttr.in/?format=%l` tells you where it thinks you are. If that's not working for you, give it the next town to your location)

Comment: @typecrazy789 I just used the promethus output because in that instance it was easiest to parse. In this instance, you can go back to using the format option as Stephan has shown.  That output is clean.  It is Partly cloudy in Amsterdam right now.

Comment: Stephan, that works perfectly, thank you. I think the Promethus makes more sense to just pull the number. I don't think we could use this for a full-on weather report, but maybe every other half hour run temperature alternating with condition and it seem natural.

Comment: Now if you really want to get wild and crazy you could [jsonextractor.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/jsonextractor.bat).  To do that you would output the weather as a json file first: `curl -s wttr.in/Amsterdam?format=j1>weather.json`.  Then you can parse the ouptput with the json extractor batch file.  To get the temp: `call jsonextractor.bat "weather.json" "current_condition[0].temp_F"`. To get the weather condition: `call jsonextractor.bat "weather.json" "current_condition[0].weatherDesc[0].value"`.

Comment: The JSON has lot of data!!! You can even get the time of sun rise: `call Parse_json.bat "weather.json" "weather[0].astronomy[0].sunrise"`

Comment: Max Temp today: `call Parse_json.bat "weather.json" "weather[0].maxtempF"`. Max Temp tomorrow:  `call Parse_json.bat "weather.json" "weather[1].maxtempF"`.  I think you can see the endless possibilities.